# An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ naturally induces a mapping on $Grass(p,n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometric-topology

I start reading about matrix manifolds and in an introduction section it is mentioned the statement below. Is it possible to provide an intuition in terms of basic (e.g. fundamental sub-spaces) linear algebra terms?

> An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ naturally induces a mapping on $Grass(p,n)$ defined by $$\mathcal{S}\in Grass(p,n) \mapsto A\mathcal{S}:=\{Ay : y \in \mathcal{S} \}$$ where $Grass(p,n)$ admits a structure of manifold called the Grassmann manifold.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The statement is actually incorrect.  Unless $\det A\ne0$, the image of $S$ under $A$ may have smaller dimension, and therefore "fall out" of the Grassmannian manifold being considered.  If $A$ is invertible, then it induces a linear isomorphism of the ambient space and the image of $S$ will have the same dimension as $S$.

Comment: Because I am not familiar with topology terminology could you please provide a little more explanations, if it is possible of course, to understand the two last statements? More specifically, statements in the first statement like "smaller dimension", "fall out", and in the second statement, like "linear isomorphism of the ambient space" and "ave the same dimension as S" can be explained with examples?

Comment: @darkmoor These are statements of linear algebra, not topology. The only thing not standard is "fall out", meaning that the dimension of the vector space $AS$ may be strictly smaller than the dimension of $S$, and so certainly is not an element of the Grassmannian of p-dimensional subspaces if $S$ was. As an example, consider the 0 matrix.